# Ember.js one api call multiple time in model hook

Tags: ember.js

I want to fill up multiple drop-down from API like below where i have to pass type parameter like 'department','priority' etc. It didn't return expected result returns data of both department and priority.

```js
//....route.js
model(){
  var _this=this;
  return Ember.RSVP.hash({
            status: _this.fetchLookup('department'),
            priority: _this.fetchLookup('priority'),
  });
},
fetchLookup(type) {
  return this.store.query('lookup', {
                    LookupType: type
                });
}
```

Comment: you mean `this.store.query` don't work well, or `Ember.RSVP` ??

Comment: this.store.query works fine but there is only one model 'lookup' attached with multiple call that's why it append the results.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably doing something wrong.

I've just tried it in a jsbin, and it works fine: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/sihacu/1/edit?html,js,output

You can even see two distinct requests logged into the console.

Comment: Thanks for your response Andrey. I have analyzed the implementation again and found that issue is occurring because API is returning id field same(start from 1 to rows count) for each lookup calls. There is only one model 'lookup' hence in store it update and insert data accordingly.
That's why dirty record appears in drop down.
There is any way to clear store before call as these are async requests that's why UnloadAll also didn't work?

Comment: Please put updated info in the question, and try to be clearer and more explicit. Provide your model definition and server replies for both requests. Write out desired and actual store content. Then send a follow-up comment, I'll have a look.